# Unir dos repositorios git

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

Hola al parecer usando IntellIJ cree un repositorio con una carpeta en especifico y otro con la carpeta general del projecto, al momento de intentar hacer push me muestra como 2 repositorios distintos como puedo unificarlos para que quede en github la carpeta con el proyecto en general.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Simplente accedi a Settings-> Version Control
Ahi elimine el directorio de la carpeta especifica, comente los cambios añadiendo el contenido esta y push.

Comment: Es una solución práctica y rápida, aunque al hacer eso perdiste el historial de cambios que realizaste en la carpeta.

Comment: De eso se trata, son 2 proyectos distintos, no dos ramas, por ende uno debe quedar limpio o bien puedes dejar uno sin editar, igualmente será parte del proyecto y podrás ver los cambios